# Facebook Integration with canonical and non-canonical page versions

Tags: php, facebook

My site has canonical and non-canonical representations of content - e.g. the poem 'Anxiety' can be viewed in it's full context at:
[canonical] http://antsmith.net/poetry/anxiety
where you can see it is 'also found in' the set of mental health tagged poems at:
[non-canonical] http://antsmith.net/poetry/anxiety/tag/mental-health

The facebook integration behaviours I want are

1. 'Liking' either URL causes the page at both URLs to be 'liked'
2. 'Sharing' either URL shares the specific URL
3. A comment added at either URL displays at both URLs
4. A comment 'also posted on facebook' posts with the specific URL

I use, on both pages

- link rel canonical = [canonical]
- og:url = [canonical]

Then on the first page for share and comment I use

- Sharing link -> [https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[non-canonical]](https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%5Bnon-canonical%5D)
- Comments Plug-in -> data-href="[canonical]"

And on the second (tag) page I tried

- Sharing link -> [https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[non-canonical]](https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%5Bnon-canonical%5D)
- Comments Plug-in -> data-href="[canonical]"

This set-up seems to properly aggregate Like counts on both pages and properly shares the appropriate URL and aggregates comments on both pages BUT when 'also posting to facebook' the created post is to the canonical URL on either page (as you'd expect since I'm passing the canonical to the data-href)

So on the second (tag) page I then tried

- Sharing link -> [http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[non-canonical]](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%5Bnon-canonical%5D)
- Comments Plug-in -> data-href="[non-canonical]"

Hoping that Facebook would use the og:url (canonical) to associate the comment and would use data-href to create the post link.

But it doesn't! Now I find comments are split...

Given these actual URLs is there anyway to specify the canonical, og:url, sharer U parameter and comment plug-in data-href to achieve the behaviours I'm looking for? Or is there some other technique I'm ignorant of?

Both URLs are live and so can be inspected.
I'm hand-coding the site in PHP 7.3.19

My Facebook integration scrip is:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '507152613230874',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v7.0'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: When I checked `http://antsmith.net/poetry/anxiety/tag/mental-health` in the debug tool, it said there was a timeout fetching the resource (re-fetching it fixed that.) But according to the canonical history presented there, you had the canonical pointing to `http://antsmith.net/poetry/anxiety/tag/mental-health` as well, since July 1st. So that was probably the reason, why pointing the comments plugin to this URL, split the comments between the two URLs. I would suggest that you test that again, now that the canonical is actually fixed and set proper.

Comment: I created the canonicalisation yesterday and tested the behaviours today, when the canonical was correct. Is it right/okay then to set data-href to the non-canonical and expect to see the behaviours I'm looking for? Also, which debug tool, I don;t see canonical history in /tools/debug...

Comment: It was likely not correct from Facebook’s perspective, because it still had the old data from July 1st cached. And yes, I am talking about the official FB debug tool, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fantsmith.net%2Fpoetry%2Fanxiety%2Ftag%2Fmental-health You should see “Canonical URL `http://antsmith.net/poetry/anxiety` (See History)” there, same as I do …?

Comment: That's really useful input - totally forget about the need to scrape again after making such changes. re. debug - no I only see (more info) which is just a doc link

Comment: And sorry, new here - is there some action I can take to add to your 'reputation' in return for your time???